# How to read through or navigate through a json object?

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript, api

I have a JSON object like this:

```
0:
    DnsAddress: "Admin DNS Address"
    IsGroup: true
    Role: Array(1)
        0:
        Assigned: { TotalUsers: 2, TotalGroups: 1 }
        Description: "Admin Role"
        Id: 3192
        Location: null
        Name: "Admin_Role"
        Permissions: Array(16)
            0: { Category: null, Resource: "Dashboard", Action: "FULL_ACCESS" }
            1: { Category: null, Resource: "Alerts", Action: "FULL_ACCESS" }
            2: { Category: null, Resource: "Inventory", Action: "FULL_ACCESS" }
            3: { Category: null, Resource: "Reports", Action: "FULL_ACCESS" }
            4: { Category: null, Resource: "OS Update", Action: "FULL_ACCESS" }
            5: { Category: null, Resource: "Software Update", Action: "FULL_ACCESS" }
            6: { Category: null, Resource: "Certificate Distribution", Action: "FULL_ACCESS" }
            7: { Category: null, Resource: "Groups and Permissions", Action: "FULL_ACCESS" }
            8: { Category: null, Resource: "General", Action: "FULL_ACCESS" }
            9: { Category: null, Resource: "KPI Data Retention", Action: "FULL_ACCESS" }
            10: { Category: null, Resource: "Email", Action: "FULL_ACCESS" }
            11: { Category: null, Resource: "Enhanced Monitor Inventory", Action: "FULL_ACCESS" }
            12: { Category: null, Resource: "Cloud Interfaces", Action: "FULL_ACCESS" }
            13: { Category: null, Resource: "Supplied Network", Action: "FULL_ACCESS" }
            14: { Category: null, Resource: "External NMS", Action: "FULL_ACCESS" }
            15: { Category: null, Resource: "Email Alert Notification", Action: "FULL_ACCESS" }
        ProductType: (6)["SMART_HOPPING_INFRASTRUCTURE", "SUPPLIED_NETWORK", "INTELLIBRIDGE_ENTERPRISE", "CAREEVENT", "UNKNOWN"]
        TotalRecords: 0            
    SourceType: "Admin Source Type"
    UserId: "System Account"
```

I need to read the permissions array[16] and get their Action, if it's Full Access or not and enable certain functions with that condition(full access or no access or read access).

How can I proceed with that?

I am getting this JSON as string from the API.

Comment: Take for example, `x = [1,2,3]`. Do you know how to log only `2`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's suppose that your json looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "DnsAddress": "Admin DNS Address",
        "IsGroup": true,
        "Role": [
            {
                "Assigned": {
                    "TotalUsers": 2,
                    "TotalGroups": 1
                },
                "Description": "Admin Role",
                "Id": 3192,
                "Location": null,
                "Name": "Admin_Role",
                "Permissions": [
                    {
                        "Category": null,
                        "Resource": "Dashboard",
                        "Action": "FULL_ACCESS"
                    },
                    {
                        "Category": null,
                        "Resource": "Alerts",
                        "Action": "FULL_ACCESS"
                    },
                    {
                        "Category": null,
                        "Resource": "Inventory",
                        "Action": "FULL_ACCESS"
                    },
                    {
                        "Category": null,
                        "Resource": "Reports",
                        "Action": "FULL_ACCESS"
                    },
                    {
                        "Category": null,
                        "Resource": "OS Update",
                        "Action": "FULL_ACCESS"
                    },
                    {
                        "Category": null,
                        "Resource": "Software Update",
                        "Action": "FULL_ACCESS"
                    },
                    {
                        "Category": null,
                        "Resource": "Certificate Distribution",
                        "Action": "FULL_ACCESS"
                    },
                    {
                        "Category": null,
                        "Resource": "Groups and Permissions",
                        "Action": "FULL_ACCESS"
                    },
                    {
                        "Category": null,
                        "Resource": "General",
                        "Action": "FULL_ACCESS"
                    },
                    {
                        "Category": null,
                        "Resource": "KPI Data Retention",
                        "Action": "FULL_ACCESS"
                    },
                    {
                        "Category": null,
                        "Resource": "Email",
                        "Action": "FULL_ACCESS"
                    },
                    {
                        "Category": null,
                        "Resource": "Enhanced Monitor Inventory",
                        "Action": "FULL_ACCESS"
                    },
                    {
                        "Category": null,
                        "Resource": "Cloud Interfaces",
                        "Action": "FULL_ACCESS"
                    },
                    {
                        "Category": null,
                        "Resource": "Supplied Network",
                        "Action": "FULL_ACCESS"
                    },
                    {
                        "Category": null,
                        "Resource": "External NMS",
                        "Action": "FULL_ACCESS"
                    },
                    {
                        "Category": null,
                        "Resource": "Email Alert Notification",
                        "Action": "FULL_ACCESS"
                    }
                ],
                "ProductType": [
                    "SMART_HOPPING_INFRASTRUCTURE",
                    "SUPPLIED_NETWORK",
                    "INTELLIBRIDGE_ENTERPRISE",
                    "CAREEVENT",
                    "UNKNOWN"
                ],
                "TotalRecords": 0
            }
        ],
        "SourceType": "Admin Source Type",
        "UserId": "System Account"
    }
]
```

you can browse with the code follow:

```
const users = JSON.parse(jsonInputs);

for(const user of users){
    for(const role of user.Role){
        for(const {Resource, Action} of role.Permissions){
            console.log(Resource, Action);
            // compute Resource and Action here
             }
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you receive a string, the first thing to parse the JSON is JSON.parse (obj). Then you work as with a regular array using methods like forEach or map. Depending on what you need